# Derivative of Kronecker product with chain rule?

Tags: matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

This is somewhat related to my previous question, but in a slightly different form and with different assumptions.

Say I have the following expression:

$\frac{\delta E}{\delta \mathbf{R}} = 2\Theta \mathbf{R}^T - 2\Phi$

where $\Phi, \Theta \text{ and } \mathbf{R}$ are all matrices.

Now, given the additional constraint:

$\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{I} \otimes \mathbf{K})$

($\mathbf{I}$ is an identity matrix, $\mathbf{B}$ is also a matrix)

How does one find $\frac{\delta E}{\delta \mathbf{K}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverting to the differential expression
$$\eqalign{
dE &= 2\,(\Theta R^T-\Phi):dR \cr
   &= 2\,(\Theta R^T-\Phi):B(I\otimes dK) \cr
   &= 2\,B^T(\Theta R^T-\Phi):I\otimes dK \cr
   &= M:I\otimes dK \cr\cr
}$$
Now you need the Kronecker factorization of $M$ 
$$\eqalign{
  M &= \sum_{j=1}^r A_j\otimes Z_j \cr
}$$
where the $A_j$ matrices are shaped like $I$, and the $Z_j$ like $K$.

Then apply the Frobenius-Kronecker mixed product rule
$$\eqalign{
  (A\otimes Z):(E\otimes F) &= (A:E)\,(Z:F) \cr
}$$
to get
$$\eqalign{
 dE &= \sum_{i=j}^r A_j\otimes Z_j : I\otimes dK \cr
    &= \sum_{i=j}^r (A_j:I)\,Z_j:dK \cr
    &= \sum_{i=j}^r {\rm tr}(A_j)\,Z_j:dK \cr\cr
\frac{\partial E}{\partial K} &= \sum_{j=1}^r\,Z_j\,{\rm tr}(A_j) \cr\cr
}$$
For help with the Kronecker factorization search for articles by van Loan and Pitsianis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm a little confused by your notation. Where do A and Z come from?

Comment: The $A_j$ and $Z_j$ matrices come from the Kronecker factorization of $M=B^T(\Theta R^T-\Phi)$.

Comment: Ok, I think I found what you're referring to.

https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/Approximation%20with%20Kronecker%20Products,%20from%20Linear%20Algebra%20for%20Large%20Scale%20and%20Real-%20Time%20Applications.pdf

I'm assuming that the factorization you're referring to is defined by equations 3 and 4?

Comment: Look at section 5.5 of the paper. You might also look for Pitsianis' PhD dissertation, which contains Matlab code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the thesis, really interesting. I seem to have got a toy problem working in MATLAB so I will try it out on my real problem. Very cool stuff.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{{\partial}}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}\def\l{\left}\def\r{\right}$Start
with hans's differential relation and rearrange it.

Assume that $K$ is $\,(m\times n)\,$ and $\,I_p$ is $\,(p\times p)$
$$\eqalign{
dE &= M:I_p\otimes dK \\
 &= M:\sum_{k=1}^p \l(e_ke_k^T\otimes dK\r) \\
 &= M:\sum_{k=1}^p \l(e_k\otimes I_m\r)\l(I_\o\otimes dK\r)\l(e_k\otimes I_n\r)^T \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^p \l(e_k\otimes I_m\r)^TM\l(e_k\otimes I_n\r):\l(I_\o\otimes dK\r) \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^p \l(e_k\otimes I_m\r)^TM\l(e_k\otimes I_n\r):dK \\
}$$
where $e_k$ is the $k^{th}$ column of $I_p\,$ and $I_\o$ is the $(\o\times\o)$ identity matrix.

Now that $dK$ has been isolated on the RHS the gradient can be trivially calculated as
$$\eqalign{
\grad{E}{K} &= \sum_{k=1}^p \l(e_k\otimes I_m\r)^TM\l(e_k\otimes I_n\r) \\
}$$